# Change svg color div hitbox

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg image. It changes color on the icon itself when you hover but it's in a div that is 60x60 and when hovering the div it doesn't change the fill color

```css
.nav-open-link {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span svg:hover #nav-open-link, span svg:hover #nav-close-link {
    fill: #fff;
}
span svg #nav-open-link, span svg #nav-close-link {
    transition: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-open-link">
 <span>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 20 16"  style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 16">
   <path id="nav-open-link" fill="#4f4f4f" d="M1,2h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1s-0.4-1-1-1H1C0.4,0,0,0.4,0,1S0.4,2,1,2z M19,7H1C0.4,7,0,7.4,0,8s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,7,19,7z M19,14H1c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,14,19,14z">
   </path>
  </svg>
  </span> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hover to work on the div, just apply it to the div rather than the path.

It's kind of confusing to have a class and an id with the same name so I removed the path id since it didn't seem to be necessary.

```css
.nav-open-link {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.nav-open-link:hover {
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-open-link">
 <span>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 20 16"  style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 16">
   <path d="M1,2h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1s-0.4-1-1-1H1C0.4,0,0,0.4,0,1S0.4,2,1,2z M19,7H1C0.4,7,0,7.4,0,8s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,7,19,7z M19,14H1c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,14,19,14z">
   </path>
  </svg>
  </span> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `fill` from `svg` and add fill color in css....see below code u'll understand

```css
.nav-open-link {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}


span svg #nav-open-link, span svg #nav-close-link {
    transition: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

svg{
  fill: #4f4f4f;
}
svg:hover{
  fill: #db4344;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-open-link">
 <span>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 20 16"  style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 16">
   <path id="nav-open-link" fill="" d="M1,2h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1s-0.4-1-1-1H1C0.4,0,0,0.4,0,1S0.4,2,1,2z M19,7H1C0.4,7,0,7.4,0,8s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,7,19,7z M19,14H1c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1h18c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1S19.6,14,19,14z">
   </path>
  </svg>
  </span> 
 </div>
```